# How to AutomationProperties for comboboxItems in xml

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add `AutomationProperties` in `comboboxItems` in XML (no code behind)? I want to set `AutomationProperties` for any selection change in `combobox`. My `Combobox` in XAML looks like:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentValue}" ItemContainerStyle="StaticResource ComboBoxItem.CommonDropDown}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Options}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
      <viewModel:BaseViewComboBoxTemplateSelector />
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Automation properties are attached properties. You may need to include the namespace

```
 xmlns:auto="Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation"
```

You use them like normal attached properties:

```
<ComboBox AutomationProperties.PropertyNameYouWantToSetGoesHere="something"> 
</Combobox>
```

---

More to read here: [windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.automationproperties)

Patterns General site: [control-patterns-and-interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/accessibility/control-patterns-and-interfaces)

For SelectionChanges you want to use [ISelectionProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation.Provider.ISelectionProvider) which is implemented for Comboboxes as/over the [windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.comboboxautomationpeer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.automation.peers.comboboxautomationpeer) when automating your app through code.

Example ([source](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2008/05/18/uiautomation-to-open-combobox-from-code/))

```
ComboBoxAutomationPeer peer = new ComboBoxAutomationPeer(yourComboBox);
IExpandCollapseProvider provider = (IExpandCollapseProvider) peer
    .GetPattern(PatternInterface.ExpandCollapse);
provider.Expand();
```

hth